# Concatenate String and Int to form file name prefix

Tags: powershell, integer, concatenation, padding

I am working with PowerShell to create a renaming script for a number of files in a directory.

Two questions here:

I have a string variable `$strPrefix = "ACV-100-"` and an integer counter `$intInc = 000001` and I wish to increment the counter `$intInc` 1 -> 2 and then concatenate the two and store it in a variable `$strCPrefix` in the following format: `ACV-100-000002`.

I believe the `$intInc` will need to be cast in order to convert it once incrementing is complete but I am unsure how to do this.

Secondly, I have found that the script will display `000001` as `1`, `000101` as `101` and so on... I need the full 6 digits to be displayed as this will form a file name. How do I keep or pad the numbers before I process the concatenation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$intInc = 1

$strCprefix = $strprefix + "{0:000000}" -f $intInc # give ACV-100-000001
```

hope can help

Comment: Why would you use a string concat ( + ) AND the `-f`? Just add it into the format string

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
$intInc = 1
...
$filename =  $strPrefix + ('0' * (6 - $intInc.ToSTring().Length)) + ($intInc++).ToString()
```