# powershell auto increment by 001

Tags: powershell, auto-increment

This is what I want to achieve.
Capture the screen and save it as **$username-$date-000.jpg**
where 000 needs to be auto-incremented every time a file is saved. (i.e 000,001,002)

I have tried to auto-generate the number. 
What am I suppose to do? 
How do I auto-increment the number?

```
$Path = read-host "Screenshot will save to - [1] Desktop or [2] C:\" 
switch ($Path)
{
        1
        {
        $Path = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\"
        }
        2
        {
        $Path = "C:\"
        }
}
$X = 0
$FileName = %{"$env:USERNAME-$(get-date -f MM-dd)-$(($X+1).ToString("000")).jpg"}
$File = "$Path\$FileName"
```

Comment: This is maybe a duplicate question.. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037710/concatenate-string-and-int-to-form-file-name-prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When giving a user the choice between to paths, I think you need to have more (3) variables to keep track of the current sequence number for that path.

Also, I would advise to make use of the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6) cmdlet to combine strings into paths.

Something like this should work:

```
# we need three index variables: 
# one for the final file name, a second one for when the user chooses to save to desktop
# and a third one for when the user selects to save to the C:\ drive.
$index = $desktopIndex = $cdriveIndex = 0

# enter a loop to make sure no other choices than '1' or '2' get through
do {
    $choice = Read-Host "Screenshot will save to - [1] Desktop or [2] C:\"     #"# let the user choose the destination
    switch ($choice) {
        '1' { 
              $Path = Join-Path -Path $env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'Desktop'
              $index = $desktopIndex++  # increment the counter for files that go to the desktop
            }
        '2' { 
              $Path = "C:\"
              $index = $cdriveIndex++   # increment the counter for files that go to the C:\ drive
            }
    }
} until ($choice -eq '1' -or $choice -eq '2')

# construct the filename using the -f format operator
$fileName = '{0}-{1:MM-dd}-{2:000}' -f $env:USERNAME, (Get-Date), $index
$file     = Join-Path -Path $Path -ChildPath $FileName
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the ideal way of doing it, but it still works:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -ne 200; $i = $i + 20) {
    $num = "0" * ( 3 - $i.ToString().Length) + $i.ToString()
    $FileName = "file-$num"
    $FileName
}
```

Here i am just getting the length of the number as a string, and adding **x** amount of 0s to the start based off 3 - {character length of number}.

So in your would need to add the calculation of the number of 0s based off x:

```
$num = "0" * ( 3 - $x.ToString().Length) + $x.ToString()
```

And your filename would be:

```
$FileName = %{"$env:USERNAME-$(get-date -f MM-dd)-$num.jpg"}
```